# U = {$x ∈ E $ : $x_1$ = $\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}$, $x_2$ = $e^{n\cos\left(\pi n\right)}$, n ∈ $\mathbb{N}$} open, closed, bouded?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

> Let  $E = \mathbb{R}^2 $ with eucledian norm.
>
> Let U = {$x ∈ E $ : $x_1$ = $\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}$, $x_2$ = $e^{n\cos\left(\pi n\right)}$, n ∈ $\mathbb{N}$}
>
> Is U open? Closed? Bounded?

We have that $e^{n\cos \left(\pi n\right)}$ = $e^n$ if $n$ is even and $e^{-n}$ if $n$ is odd. And we also have that $\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}$ = $1/{(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n})}$. Where do I go from here? The assistant said that the set is neither open nor closed. And it is not closed because it approaches $0$, but $0$ is not in the set. So far I've tried using the definition of open/closed/bounded sets but I can't find a suitable delta. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: **Hint :** $U$ is not open because it is countable (why ?). $U$ is not closed because $0$ is in the closure of $U$, but not if $U$ (why ?). $U$ is not bounded (why ?).

Answer (score 0):

$U$ is a countable set. No countable set can be open because if it is open it would contain some open ball and open balls are uncountable.

The set is not bounded because $(\sqrt {2n+1}-\sqrt {2n}, e^{2n})$ is in it for each $n$.

The set is not closed since $(0,0)$ does not belong to it though it is a limit point.